# Android HERE SDK. How to add info bubble to a MapPolyline

Tags: android, here-api, infobubble

I have a question about infobubble in HERE map SDK. My application is plotting MapPolylines and laying out on the Map. What I need is how to add infobubble when I clicked one of the Polylines.

I am trying to extend the functionality of MapMarker and did some implementations but it is not possible.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapMarkers can show static images and can show an android view if it is tapped. Is this what you are looking for?

Perhaps you can register a MapGesterListener and listen to tap events? When a tap is received, you can call Map.pixelToGeo( PointF ) and put a map marker there with a static image.

Comment: Thanks David, I should use the Mapmarker info bubble without tying up with the MapPolyline. You mentioned that I can use android view when MapMarker is tapped, can I customized the info bubble with events in case I put buttons on it. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately no, we only use the view to generate an image. You can only get a simple click event back from it.